# Scrolling is not smooth as native app for ionic 2 in iOS platform

Tags: ios, scroll, ionic2

I've build an iOS app in ionic 2  and the scrolling is not as smooth in list & grid as in native app, can anyone help me with the solution? I am using xcode 8.3.2 & iOS 10.3.2 device.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: you can try virtual scroll,https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/ for better and faster scrolling

Comment: for IOS platform, the Virtual scroll is also dependent on WKwebviewEngine.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin helped me to achieve native smooth scroll on some views: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Comment: What are the some view?? Please specify. Is it ion-list?

Comment: I had problems to achieve smooth scroll on views with infinite scroll used.. after use of mentioned plugin, the problem was solved.

Comment: This plugin requires CORS to be enabled on the server. so is there any way to use this plugin without CORS enable.

Comment: @AtifHussain could you point me to the CORS requirement? I am sure that I was not allowing CORS on server. Thanks

Comment: @Luckylooke Do you want to implement CORS on server?

Comment: I got the smooth behaviour by showing less data on UI item. by using infinite scroll.

Comment: @AtifHussain I was asking, where is the CORS requirement mentioned? You wrote: "This plugin requires CORS to be enabled on the server" why? Who said that?

Comment: Ok, I did not remember this, I can check code in app when I will have more time, because it is not in my actual project.